# Windows keypad keycodes not working

Tags: jquery, windows

I added a simple mask to an text input that only allows numbers to be inputted. I did it using the following code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $("#zip").keydown(function(event) {
            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
    });
```

The issue I'm coming across is that the keypad numbers aren't working on Windows (they work find on Macs). However, the numbers found on the top row of the keyboard work fine. Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including keycodes for the numberpad in your if statement. This should work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#zip").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $("#zip").keydown(function(event) {
            var code = e.keycode || e.which
            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if ( code  == 46 || code  == 8 ) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (code  < 48 || code  > 57 ) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
    });
```